# How to add CSS on specific element while using pseudo-class or pseudo element

Tags: javascript, html, css

This are 5 pieces `a href` and when hover unto them `Hello World!!` would show up unto there rigth side.. How can I make `Hello World!!`only show on `Only Here` when hover? Is there like

```
<a style =":hover::after display: inline-block; content: "Hello World!!"; font-size: 16px; ... etc " href="#">
```

POC coding argument of some sort to design specific element while using pseudo-class or pseudo element

```css
a:hover::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "Hello World!!";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Not Here</a><br>
<a href="#">Not Here</a><br>
<a href="#">Only Here</a><br>
<a href="#">Not Here</a><br>
<a href="#">Not Here</a><br>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with your English. Please revise to be more clear about what you want to behave differently. Also, I'm not sure what the first code example is for. Inline styles are ugly and can't contain selectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want to chieve?

```css
a.hello:hover::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "Hello World!!";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Not Here</a><br>
<a href="#">Not Here</a><br>
<a class="hello" href="#">Only Here</a><br>
<a href="#">Not Here</a><br>
<a href="#">Not Here</a><br>
```

Comment: I understand the concept now so i just used `#id` or `.class` of the element depending on availability?? also the snippet you provided i can remove `a` from `a.hello:hover` and left with `.hello:hover` which still work as expected so  `a ` is optional??

Comment: Yes, you can do all that. Try it.